# How to unmerge cells in excel worksheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a class that represents a worksheet in Excel. I would like to get rid of all merged cells using `unmerge_cells` function. When I am running the code I can see (comparing to my excel worksheet) that all ranges from the list are passed correctly, but the range does not seem to be unmerged.. None of ranges have been unmerged.. What am I overseeing?

```
from openpyxl.utils import *


class ExcelSheet(object):
    """

    This class represents excel worksheet.
    Attributes:

        sheet_obj - excel worksheet object
        self.merged_cells_ranges - list of ranges with merged cells

    """
    def __init__(self, sheet_obj):
        self.sheet_obj = sheet_obj
        self.merged_cells_ranges = self.sheet_obj.merged_cell_ranges


    def unmerge_cells(self):
        if len(self.merged_cells_ranges) > 0:
            for range in self.merged_cells_ranges:
                self.sheet_obj.unmerge_cells(range)
```

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to set `ws.merged_cells = []`

Comment: @krakowi How did you solve it?

Comment: Hi @Joe, as advised by Charlie Clark. I wrote short method which sets merged_cells (an attribute of sheet_obj) to an empty list. That entirely 'clears' the whole workbook.

Comment: @krakowi Could you please post the method as answer? :)

Comment: `def unmerge_cells(self):
        self.sheet_obj.merged_cells = []`

Comment: @krakowi thanks, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
unmerge_cells(range_string=None, start_row=None, start_column=None, end_row=None, end_column=None)
```

`range_string` is a cell range (e.g. A1:E1)

You need to pass the range as a string.